# Problems opening a SQLITE database from PHP and reporting outcomes to the HTML page

Tags: php

I am new to PHP.
I need to open a database and delete an entry, however I don't want to create a new db if it doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist, I'd like to return an error to the HTML page from which the query originated.

Problem is that neither

```
   echo "Unable to open database\n";
```

nor

```
echo "entry deleted\n";
```

nor the

```
alert("entry deleted");
```

show on the browser's console or on the webpage despite the fact that the entry is successfully deleted. I am using Safari on Mac. HTML page logs appear on the console but PHP pages logs don't. Also the alert does not pop up if invoked from the PHP page.

I want to have full control of the success / no success of the operation, so that this info can be fed back to the HTML page and other methods can be triggered accordingly.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('myDb.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db)
   {
       echo "Database does not exist";

   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";

       //Do something (delete entry)    

       echo "entry deleted\n";
       alert("entry deleted");
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$db` will always be an instance of MyDB class, it can't really be evaluated in a `if` because it will always be truthy. So the code `echo "Database does not exist";` won't ever run.

Also, php doesn't output to the browser console. And there's no `alert` function built-in in php (but not sure if you have that defined somewhere else).

From the docs, `SQLite3::open` doesn't return anything, and it doesn't state if it throws an exception if can't open the database. The docs says that `SQLite3::__construct` throws an exception if it can't connect, so you should stick to that (and don't use the `class MyDB` example from `SQLite3::open`).

```
try {
    $db = new SQLite3();

    echo "Opened database successfully\n";

    //Do something (delete entry)    

    echo "entry deleted\n";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // database does not exists
    ...
}

Would need to check your `//Do something (delete entry)` code to be sure that it's not returning earlier.
```